# How do I use loops with discord reactions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to code a fighting discord bot game but I ran into troubles lately!

Everything works with reactions.
So basically what i want to do is : roll a dice to determine the one who starts. The winner rolls 2 dices to determine the damages he will do and then its player 2's turn.

Until here, everything works.

What i would like it to do is loop this last part when the first player rolls the 2 dices to inflict damages.

I tried placing while loops userhealth<=0 here and there, but it never works.

I know it has to do with promises and stuff like that, but Im still lost.
A little help would be appreciated!
Here is the code:

```js
const { ReactionCollector } = require('discord.js');

function rolldice(numero){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * numero + 1);
}

function premier(msg,user){
  diceroll1 = rolldice(20)
  diceroll2 = rolldice(20)
  msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.tag} a eu : ${diceroll1} \n\n ${user.tag} a eu : ${diceroll2}`)


  if(diceroll1 > diceroll2){
    msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.tag} gagne`)
    return msg.author.id
  }
  else if(diceroll1 < diceroll2){
    msg.channel.send(`${user.tag} gagne`)
    return user.id
    
  }
  else{
    msg.channel.send(`Vous avez fait égalité. On recommence le tirage.`)
    premier(msg,user)
  }
}

function attaque1(msg, user){
  damagedice1 = rolldice(6)
  damagedice2 = rolldice(6)
  somme = damagedice1 + damagedice2
  return {somme,damagedice1,damagedice2}
}

function bagarre(msg,user,winner,user1health,user2health,fighter1,fighter2){
  if(winner === msg.author.id){
    msg.channel.send(`Joueur 1 Clique sur  pour determiner les dégats que tu vas infliger.`).then((riposte) => {
      riposte.react('')
      var atksmme = attaque1(msg,user)
      const filter1 = (reaction, user) => {
        return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === fighter1;
      };
      const collector1 = riposte.createReactionCollector(filter1,{
        max: 1
      });
      collector1.on('collect',(collected,reason) => {
        user2health = user2health - atksmme.somme
        msg.channel.send(`${msg.author.tag} inflige ${atksmme.somme} de dégâts à ${user.tag}! (${atksmme.damagedice1} + ${atksmme.damagedice2})`)
        msg.channel.send(`Il reste ${user2health} points de vie à ${user.tag}`)
        if(user2health<=0) return msg.channel.send('Vous avez perdu')
        collector1.stop()


        msg.channel.send(`Joueur 2 Clique sur  pour determiner les dégats que tu vas infliger.`).then((riposte1) => {
          riposte1.react('')
          var atk2smme = attaque1(msg,user)
          const filter2 = (reaction, user) => {
            return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === fighter2;
          };
          const collector2 = riposte1.createReactionCollector(filter2,{
            max: 1
          });
          collector2.on('collect',(collected,reason) => {
            user1health = user1health - atk2smme.somme
            msg.channel.send(`${user.tag} inflige ${atk2smme.somme} de dégâts à ${msg.author.tag}! (${atk2smme.damagedice1} + ${atk2smme.damagedice2})`)
            msg.channel.send(`Il reste ${user1health} points de vie à ${msg.author.tag}`)
            if(user1health<=0) return msg.channel.send('Vous avez perdu')
            collector2.stop()
        })
        })
      })
    })



}
else if(winner === user.id){
  var atksmme = attaque1(msg,user)
  user1health = user1health - atksmme.somme
  msg.channel.send(`${user.tag} inflige ${atksmme.somme} de dégâts à ${msg.author.tag}! (${atksmme.damagedice1} + ${atksmme.damagedice2})`)
  msg.channel.send(`Il reste ${user1health} points de vie à ${msg.author.tag}`)
  }

}

module.exports = {
  name: 'fight',
  args :  true,
  usage : '@<user>',
  async execute(msg,args) {
    //VARIABLES
    const { client } = msg;
    var diceroll1;
    var diceroll2;
    var damagedice1;
    var damagedice2;
    var user1health = 12;
    var user2health = 12;
    var winner;


    //checks if the username to fight is in the msg
    var author1 = msg.author.username;
    var user = msg.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return msg.reply("you did not specify who you would like to fight!");
    //checks if the users is trying to fight themselves
    if(user.id == msg.author.id) return msg.reply('you cannot fight yourself!');
    //checks if the user is trying to fight the bot
    if(user.bot ==  true)
        return msg.reply('you cannot fight a bot!');

    //saves the two user ids to variables
    var fighter1 = msg.author.id;
    var fighter2 = user.id;
    var challenged = user.toString();


    msg.channel.send(`${challenged}, tu veux te battre?`).then((bataille) => {
      bataille.react('')

      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return [''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === fighter2;
      };

      const collector = bataille.createReactionCollector(filter,{
        max: 1
      });

      collector.on('collect',(collected,reason) => {
        winner = premier(msg,user)
        bagarre(msg,user,winner,user1health,user2health,fighter1,fighter2)
      })
    })
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's a lot of weird things about this.

First of all, there are a lot of unused variables. Please use a proper IDE like Visual Studio Code that informs you about these things.

Second, you should be using `await` instead of `then` in most cases. (dont just replace then with await - see javascript async tutorials for good examples)

Third, this is just all a mess. You will have to divide your code into more functions: Create a function to initiate an attack from one user to another. That code should be usable for both player 1 and 2 so that no code is copypasted for both players. Then you can just call that function after one player has made their turn to start the next turn for the other player.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
For the variables, there are juste the 4 diceroll and damagedice that i use in the functions above, i just forgot to delete them at the begining of the execute, otherwise i dont see that much unused variables.
Alright i'm gonna check out async tutorials! And gonna create the function you said!